# Error when accessing xml nodes

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have an xml as follows

```
<Students xmlns="http://AdapterTest">
<Schema name="Schema1" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-data" xmlns:dt="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes">
    <ElementType name="Student" content="empty" model="closed">
        <AttributeType name="Student_id" dt:type="string"/>
        <AttributeType name="Student_Name" dt:type="string"/>
        <attribute type="Student_id"/>
        <attribute type="Student_Name"/>
    </ElementType>
</Schema>
<Student Student_id="123456" Student_Name="Udaya" xmlns="x-schema:#Schema1"/>
<Student Student_id="568923" Student_Name="Christie" xmlns="x-schema:#Schema1"/>
<Student Student_id="741852" Student_Name="Test Name" xmlns="x-schema:#Schema1"/>
<Student Student_id="852789" Student_Name="Sample Name" xmlns="x-schema:#Schema1"/>
</Students>
```

In my application I am trying to access the nodes using LINQ as follows.

```
XDocument xdoc1 = XDocument.Load("Customer.xml");

        List<Student> studentList =
            (from _student in xdoc1.Element("Students").Elements("Student")
             select new Student
             {
                 firstName = _student.Attribute("Student_id").Value,
                 lastName = _student.Attribute("Student_Name").Value,


             }).ToList();
```

It gives me an Object reference not set to an instance of an object.When I remove the xmlns="http://AdapterTest" from the root element it works fine. What I am missing here

Comment: could be a copy & paste error, but did you close the <Students> tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ive had a similar problem before like this. Like you said if you remove the namespace from the xml it works. You have to do something like this:

```
XNamespace rootNs = xdoc1.Root.Name.Namespace;
XNamespace studentNS = "x-schema:#Schema1";
```

And then when selecting nodes prepend the selector with ns, like:

```
var yourStudentList = xdoc1.Element(rootNS + "Student").Elements(studentNS + "Student");
```

I havent tested this but it looks similar to and issue i have had.

Comment: I used this.Now the error is not populating. But It want give me the result.The List is empty. Though I need to get the 4 elements in the List

Comment: Your selection is wrong then. Use both the namespaces you have in your xml ie The root namespace and the student namespace. I will update for you.

Comment: @udaya726 See my update. You will have to iterate over yourStudentList using the correct namespaces then it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Add namespaces:

```
        XNamespace ns1 = xdoc1.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();
        XNamespace ns2 = "x-schema:#Schema1";
```

and use them when retrieving elements:

```
        List<Student> studentList =
            (from _student in xdoc1.Element(ns1 + "Students")
                                   .Elements(ns2 + "Student")
             select new Student
             {
                 firstName = _student.Attribute("Student_id").Value,
                 lastName = _student.Attribute("Student_Name").Value,
             }).ToList();
```

And you'll get the list with four elements.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a namespace for LINQ.

```
XDocument xdoc1 = XDocument.Load("Customer.xml");
XNamespace ns = "http://AdapterTest"; //definine namespace

    List<Student> studentList =
        (from _student in xdoc1.Element(ns + "Students").Elements("Student")
         select new Student
         {
             firstName = _student.Attribute("Student_id").Value,
             lastName = _student.Attribute("Student_Name").Value,


         }).ToList();
```